# How Do I filter data with EF and a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filtering

I have a list which I would like to use to filter the data from the database.
I want to count number of rows that matches in the databases.

But I keep getting syntax error problem.

Any ideas what is wrong?

```
List<EmployeeInfo> list = new List<EmployeeInfo>();

// EmployeeInfo(company, employeer, employeeId)

list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 1))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 2))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 3))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 3, 1))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 3, 6))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 4, 2))
list.add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 5, 3))

// I want to count the number of rows that matches the criteria list. Example: 
// But it is not working. 
int count = Model.Points.Count(x => x.companyId = list[0].CompanyId &&
list.Contains(e => e.Employeer == x.employeeId && e.employeeId == x.employeeId);
```

Comment: You are missing an equal sign : x.companyId == list[0].CompanyId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
            List<EmployeeInfo> list = new List<EmployeeInfo>();

            // EmployeeInfo(company, employeer, employeeId)

            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 1));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 2));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 2, 3));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 3, 1));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 3, 6));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 4, 2));
            list.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, 5, 3));

            // I want to count the number of rows that matches the criteria list. Example: 
            // But it is not working. 
            int count = Model.Points.Count(x => x.companyId == list[0].CompanyId 
                && list.Any(e => e.Employeer == x.employeeId && e.employeeId == x.employeeId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing an = in x.companyId = list[0]
your count statement should be

```
int count = Model.Points.Count(x => x.companyId == list[0].CompanyId && list.Contains(e => e.Employeer == x.employeeId && e.employeeId == x.employeeId);
```